# I am getting an Error when I tried to Upload a file (image of jpg/png) with Cypress and Java script

Tags: javascript-objects, cypress, browser-automation, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-psoc

```
//Click on File Upload and upload the DL
cy.get('p').contains('Upload your Document').parent('span').parent('button').click();
cy.fixture('./testData/JamesBondDL.png').then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('p').contains('Front Side').parent('div>div').find('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
    fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
    fileName: 'JamesBond.png',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  });
});
```

// I have added the import package under cypress/support/commands.js
// i.e   import 'cypress-file-upload';

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: 1. In Network tab , I see the "Invalidate" error (400 Bad request) as shown below :=>

{"code":2000,"message":"Token not found"}


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------2. Also There is a "Document" error (400 Bad request) after the above error :=>

{"referenceId":"a1df15aa-883a-460e-9235-cb192611c721","data":{"allowedFormats":[".png",".bmp",".jpg",".tif",".gif"]},"msg":"DocumentVerificationFileFormatNotSupported"}

Comment: @Bhushan look like you need to login/auth yourself for file upload operation.

Comment: @Tej-work, As this is UI Automation, I have to login with Username and Password to submit an application (Which I have automated already ) but in the flow I am getting this type of issue... Please let me know if there is any code issue

Comment: @Bhushan can you share error (cypress runner screenshot)?

Comment: @Tej-work , Please find attached the error screenshot in test runner, a broken Image is shown instead of the image uploaded in application (Basically there is no error shown in test runner logs - but if I go to developers view -> network tab there is 400 error code, shown in screenshot as well) .